# What is a python code for duplicating words that have the number 2 behind it?

Tags: python, regex, duplicates

For e.g., if the string is really2, I want to replace it as really-really.

I want the duplicated words hyphenated as well.

Can I avoid using RegEx?

Thanks so  much!

Comment: You do not need a regex for this, unless you precise the requirements.

Comment: You only want 2 to work? What if the string is "really3"? or "really22"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can do it without regex, it would be much easier to do it with regex. The code will be more readable and can be easily modifiable, if needed

```
import re
s = "if the string is really2, I want to replace it"
re.sub(r'(\w+)2', r'\1-\1', s)
# 'if the string is really-really, I want to replace it'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need regex for this:

```
>>> a = 'blah foo2 bar'
>>> ' '.join((i[:-1]+'-'+i[:-1]) if i.endswith('2') else i for i in a.split()) 
'blah foo-foo bar'
>>>
```

It might get more complicated if you decide to include all other numbers and repeat the word several times. But since you only asked about duplicating -- this one works well enough.